# iOS SDK - Navigation bar on Peep View CController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an iOS Swift app which I am implementing 3D Touch Peek and Pop for. It's pretty simple, a navigation controller which embeds a table view controller in which when you tap a cell segues to another table view controller.

I am using Storyboards and targeting iOS >=9.1 so I used the option in Interface Builder to add the commit and preview segues to be the same as my action segue (i.e. pushes the second table view controller onto the stack).

However when I test the "peek" in my app, it shows the second table view controller but there is no header bar (as I assume this is part of the navigation controller). When I "pop" into it, it appears as normal.

Is there a way of adding some kind of header to my table view controller whilst in "peek" mode? I assume I could just segue to a separate view controller for peek purposes, but this seems a bit wasteful.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end by implementing the `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` method of the UITableViewDataSource. It's not quite the look I wanted but perfectly functional. As there is only one "section" in my table it is a de-facto header.

I suppose if one wanted a custom view instead in the header I could use `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` in the UITableViewDelegate instead.